# Concat value on values array

Tags: javascript, charts

```
<script>
        zingchart.render({
            id: 'myChart',
            data: {
                type: 'line',
                series: [{
                        values: [54, 23, 34, 23, 43],
                    }, ]
            },
            height: 400,
            width: 600
        });
        zingchart.data.series[o].values.concat(60);
</script>
```

Some help to concat a value on values array? I can't D:
I tried with "zingchart.data.series[o].values.concat(60);
" but doesn't work.

Comment: you need to refer the docs to modify the render object after setting it

Comment: The problem may be that `[o]` should be `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`concat` returns a new array and won't modify original array while your whole purpose is to do that.

You can use `push` instead, which mutate the array.